# VBA Excel Sumif and sumifs function

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010, vba7, vba6

**Sales Details**

| Month | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| January | 120 |
| March | 250 |
| April | 380 |
| June | 510 |
| January | 640 |
| March | 770 |
| April | 900 |
| June | 1030 |
| January | 1160 |
| March | 1290 |
| April | 1420 |
| January | 1550 |

Noted: all vba code write below.........

```vb
Sub sum_if_Function()

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

'Note:rng means range**
Dim rng1(4 To 15) As Variant
Dim rng2(4 To 15) As Long
Dim Result As Long

'Note: This below code write for store all Month Name**
For i = 4 To 15
  rng1(i) = Cells(i, 3).Value
Next i

'Note: This below code write for store all Each Month Sale Amount**
For j = 4 To 15
  rng2(j) = Cells(i, 4).Value
Next j

'Note: This below code write for display January month total sales**
For i = 4 To 15
  Result = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(rng1(i), "January", rng2(i))
Next i

MsgBox "January Month Total Sales Amount:-" & Result

End Sub
```

this is my VBA code where i am trying to get January month total sales but when i run this code then vba excel compile display as massage ...run time error "424" object required

I am also tried to use two dimension array for get this result but i am failed

i need good and easy code using array so that i can get the result and also need suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass a ranges to `SumIf` - not *values* in an array!

Try this:

```vb
Sub sum_if_Function()
Dim rgMonths As Range
Set rgMonths = ActiveSheet.Range("C4:C15")

Dim rgAmount As Range
Set rgAmount = ActiveSheet.Range("D4:D15")

Dim result As Single
result = Application.WorksheetFunction.sumIF(rgMonths, "January", rgAmount)

MsgBox "January Month Total Sales Amount:-" & result
End Sub
```

Comment: Many Many thanks for this code. but how can i do it by using single dimension array or two dimension array????

Comment: Then you can't use the worksheet function. Why do you want to do that? If you want to calculate the sum - you have to sum the values "manually"

Comment: actually  i am trying to use array instead of range. Yes i can sum the value manually but i want to learn VBA program because of i am a new learner

Comment: Then you have to learn that the `sumIf` only accepts a range - that's how it works.

Answer (score 0):

If your original data is in a sheet, the preferred version is to use `SumIF` function as proposed by @Ike.
But if your original data are not from the sheet you can adopt another variant like below (I have used a template from @Ike's answer).

```
Sub Sum_by_months()
    Dim rgMonths As Variant
    rgMonths = ActiveSheet.Range("C4:C15").Value

    Dim rgAmount As Variant
    rgAmount = ActiveSheet.Range("D4:D15").Value

    Dim result As Variant
    With Application  ' not .WorksheetFunction
        result = .SumProduct(.IfError(.Match(rgMonths, Array("January"), 0), 0), rgAmount)
    End With
    MsgBox "January Month Total Sales Amount: " & result
End Sub
```

Be careful. Don't use `WorksheetFunction` object, the name of the month must be an array.